# Is it ethical to edit someone else's Questions or comments?

Tags: discussion, editing

Why not make comments on what you feel should change and let the author do it, or better yet, privately message the author and suggest. It just seems really tacky and rude to edit someone else's work with out permission.

Comment: I think @BrianBallsunStanton gave a great answer, but if you want to talk about it you're welcome to bring it up in [chat].

Comment: It's worth noting that there is no method of private message here. Everything is public - both publicly viewable and publicly "owned." Anything you write here, you give to the RPG SE community. Don't put anything you're not comfortable giving away.

Comment: In general you should probably spend some time with the help center (http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help), it'll explain more how we do things here and let you be a more effective site participant.

Comment: Some changes aren't subjective.  Your second sentence was missing a period.  I added it.  I expect that you'd have done it yourself had you seen me comment on it.  But I don't know when you'll do that or if you're even coming back to the site.  I'd rather just edit it now and be done with it.  That period is undisputable though.  If I took exception to tacky and rude and wanted them rephrased or elaborated on, that's something I'd ask you to do.

Answer (score 32):

#### Absolutely. It is both ethical and moral, according to the community precepts established in the Stack Exchange.

We are not a forum. We believe in improving, as a group, both questions and answers. If you take a look at our help center, [editing](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help/editing) states:

> All contributions are licensed under Creative Commons, and this site is collaboratively edited, like Wikipedia. If you see something that needs improvement, click edit!
>
> Editing is important for keeping questions and answers clear, relevant, and up-to-date. If you are not comfortable with the idea of your contributions being collaboratively edited by other trusted users, this may not be the site for you.

One of the specific provisions encouraged for editing is:

> - To include additional information only found in comments, so all of the information relevant to the post is contained in one place

As comments can be deleted, it makes more sense to add the information to the question/answer. This way the extra info won't be lost, and is easier to see for other users in the future.

Furthermore, because we are not a forum we don't *have* a private messaging function. The closest we've got is tagging someone in a comment on the post or in the public (Google-indexed!) chat room.